# Spring using JNDI with Tomcat... why do I need a META-INF/context.xml in my project

Tags: spring, tomcat6, jndi

I am trying to get Spring working with tomcat JNDI resource to access my database.  My project works if a META-INF/context.xml in my project with the resource information but once I remove it it stops.. why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deploy a Web application in Tomcat, in the deployment process, Tomcat will copy the META-INF/context.xml file in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/ so the context will be available for your application. Take in mind, that if you remove context.xml from you application because you dont want it, you also have to delete it manually from $CATALINA_HOME/conf/

If you have edited the server.xml for including your dababase resource and is not working when you remove context.xml it could be because you made some mistake defining your resourde in server.xml

**UPDATED**:

When resource is in server.xml, in context you should make a reference to global resource in server.xml. For example:

```
<Context crossContext="true" reloadable="true" >
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/myApp" type="javax.sql.DataSource" global="jdbc/myApp" />
</Context>
```

Comment: I copy the lines from my context.xml and put them into my server.xml, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to `Spring`.

To use JNDI you are expected to define the various resources either as global configuration or as application specifici configuration. For example [JNDI DataSource Configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Why do you expect it to work in any other case? How would Tomcat know which resources to provide if you don't define them?

**UPDATE:**
You define a resouce in your `server.xml` but you have to ***associate*** the resource with your web application. That is why you also need to modify `context.xml`

Comment: I put it in the server.xml in tomcat

Comment: @StutteringJohn:Updated answer

Comment: but my SA does not want any database information in the war file.  This is why we are trying to move it out of the project and just use JNDI for it...