# JNDI Resource Definition in Apache Tomcat 6

Tags: spring, tomcat6, jndi

I'm more than inexperienced with Apache Tomcat, so forgive me if it's a trivial question I'm asking.

My task is to change a rather big program so that it uses the connection from Tomcat instead of its own bean, so that you don't have to rebuild the code when the database changes.

This is the original bean definition (slightly changed - passwords and such...):

```
<bean id="ProjectDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" scope="singleton">
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:as400://127.0.0.1/TEST2;prompt=false;naming=sql;errors=full;date format=usa;date separator=/;time format=hms;time separator=:;transaction isolation=read committed;"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"/>
        <property name="username" value="asdf"/>
        <property name="password" value="asdf"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="${ProjectDS.initialSize}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="${ProjectDS.maxActive}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${ProjectDS.maxIdle}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="${ProjectDS.minIdle}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${ProjectDS.testOnBorrow}"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="${ProjectDS.removeAbandoned}"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="${ProjectDS.removeAbandonedTimeout}"/>
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="${ProjectDS.logAbandoned}"/>
    </bean>
```

After reading several tutorials about Tomcat configuration, I did the following:

The new bean:

```
<bean id="ProjectDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>ProjectDS</value>
        </property>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"></property>
    </bean>
```

server.xml :

```
<Resource name="ProjectDS" global="ProjectDS" auth="Container"
            type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
            url="jdbc:as400://127.0.0.1/TEST2"
            username="asdf"
            password="asdf" />
```

context.xml:

```
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <ResourceLink global="ProjectDS" name="ProjectDS" type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"/>
```

What I get is:

> Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
>   javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance

I read somewhere that I shouldn't put the above into the server.xml but into the web.xml, but I don't know where exactly. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I found this other solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841109/how-to-change-spring-to-use-datasource-from-tomcat-vs-basicdatasource but it also gives me error messages (Error listenerStart) when I try it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, rollback your `context.xml` and `server.xml` in your tomcat and/or. Here is a working configuration:

Create a file in `src/main/webapp/META-INF` named `context.xml` which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="ProjectDS" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
            url="jdbc:as400://127.0.0.1/TEST2"
            username="asdf"
            password="asdf" /> 
</Context>
```

Then, edit your bean in this way:

```
<bean id="ProjectDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/ProjectDS" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

Difference here is the `java:comp/env/ProjectDS` and the proxy unterface.

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, first the way you said it, then I included the first part into the Apache's context.xml instead. Both times the program gave me this error message:

13.04.2012 12:37:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error listenerStart
13.04.2012 12:37:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/rotrajServer] startup failed due to previous errors
.......

Comment: Could you give me more of the stacktrace plz?

Comment: This is as much as I can post in here:

16.04.2012 09:59:11 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
16.04.2012 09:59:11 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/myServer] startup failed due to previous errors
16.04.2012 09:59:11 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/myServer] registered the JDBC driver [com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

Comment: Scratch that... I seem to have messed up somewhere else. I got the old files from a backup and started anew with your solution, then it worked. Thanks a lot!